# Python returns empty dataframe, even though there are matching values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, encoding

I am trying to look through a .csv for rows with a value matching "2. Borgere > 65". There are five rows in my .csv where the fist column matches the word, however pandas return an empty DataFarme. I've tried loading up the .csv both in ISO 8859-1 and Latin-1, but same result.

Here's my code:

```
#LOAD NØGLETAL IN PANDAS
df_noegletal = pd.read_csv("zipfiler/Vaccine_maalgrupper_DB/Noegletal_vacc_daekning.csv", encoding="Latin-1")

#PRINT ROWS MATCHING VALUE
print(df_noegletal[df_noegletal.eq("2. Borgere > 65").any(1)])
```

Pandas returns the following:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Målgruppe, Ansættelsessted, Bopælsregion, Population, Antal førstevaccinerede, Antal færdigvaccinerede, Førstegangs vaccinerede dækning (%), Færdigvaccinerede dækning (%)]
Index: []

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Even though there are values in my .csv that match "2. Borgere > 65".

[This is a screenshot from my .csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WABvU.png)

Comment: Are you really sure it matches *exactly*, including white space?

Answer (score 0):

Try to access it with the column name.

It's hard to use Norway(?) variables :)

so for example:

```
df_noegletal = df_noegletal[df_noegletal['Malgruppe'].str.strip == '2. Borgere > 65']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code compares the whole DataFrame with a string, which is obviously not true.

```
df_noegletal.eq("2. Borgere > 65")
```

The syntax should be as follows:

```
df_noegletal[df_noegletal['Målgruppe' == "2. Borgere > 65"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The questions has been solved. No cell did indeed match the value. The problem was I had used commas as a seperator when opening the .csv in Excel splitting what was meant to be a single column into two. The actual value of the cell was "2. Borgere > 65, praktisk hjælp og personlig pleje". Thanks everyone.